# Create a layout inspector *.li file with Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android-studio, layout-inspector

In Android Studio 3.x (and before) when I ran the Layout inspector, the view hierarchy was automatically captured and saved in a `*.li` file. When I start the Layout Inspector in Android Studio 4.0, the view hierarchy is not saved anywhere.

Can I somehow export the view hierarchy from the new Layout Inspector to a file, so I am able to share it with others? For now I can say that I'm only able to open the `*.li` files in AS 4.0, but not save it.

Comment: Are you able to find how to save the layout inspector in 4.0 as .li file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one solution for the above case. You need to type shift two times and then type legacy layout inspector. The old layout inspector will open and you can save its .li file.

I found it useful because I can do it in the Android Studio 4.0.
I can use new feature from Android Studio 4.0 Layout Inspector as well can save .li file using the legacy layout inspector.

Comment: Bullseye, this is what I needed, thaks. It's a pity it's not exposed so it can be found more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to disable the `Live Layout Inspector` feature in the Android Studio Preferences window. It can be found in the `Experimental` section, as in the screenshot below:

[image]